# Retrieve firestore records based on Date object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created the created_date field in Firestore as **Asia/Kolkata** timezone.

But when I execute the below query not able to retrieve record shown in the screenshot.
[image]

```
let start_date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"});
start_date = new Date(start_date);
let end_date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"});
end_date = new Date(end_date);
start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() - 1);
start_date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
end_date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
admin.firestore().collection('feed')
      .orderBy('created_date')
      .where('created_date', '>', start_date)
      .where('created_date', '<', end_date)
```

**Note:** This is running in firebase-functions.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Date and Firestore Timestamp objects don't have a concept of a timezone.  What you're seeing in the Firebase console (or when you log the value with console.log()) is just your local timezome.  A Date object is really just a single number, and a Timestamp is just two numbers, that represent an offset from the unix epoch.  The point in time represented by that offset is the same for everyone around the world.

Because there are no timezones encoded in those objects, What you're doing by converting a Date to a string, then back to a Date again isn't doing what you think.  If you want to encode a Date object using a timezone, that's OK.  It will help the Date object figure out the exact moment in time.  But that timezone information is lost.

FYI you don't need to convert a Date into a Timestamp in order to use it in a query,  You can just pass the Date object directly, and the Firestore SDK will automatically convert it.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I have updated the code, Even though I am not getting what I looking for. Can you please tell me where I am doing wrong